# Update, find/replace for xml field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Page table in my database.
Lets say for simplicity it has two columns; title and xmlData
It has Title something like "my example "
and I have a xml field that looks like:

```
<MA>
  <A>
    <URL>my-example-</URL>
    <id>5</id>
    </A>
</MA>
```

1. I am trying to do a find replace of any url that has "-" at the end, and remove the only the last trailing "-" if it exists
2. and remove the trailing space(if it has one, to title)

I am able to grab the rows that need to be changed by doing

```
select * from Pages
where title like '% '
```

(there is some joins and stuff, but that is basically it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace one occurrence of the URL for each row. By the look of your sample XML you have only one URL per row.

```
with C1 as
(
  select xmlData,
         xmlData.value('(/MA/A/URL/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') as URL
  from Pages
),
C2 as
(
  select xmlData,
         URL,
         left(URL, len(URL) - 1) as URL2
  from C1
  where right(URL, 1) = '-'
)
update C2 
set xmlData.modify('replace value of (/MA/A/URL/text())[1] 
                    with sql:column("C2.URL2")')
```

Extract the URL value in CTE C1.
Remove the last '-' from the URL and put that in URL2 in CTE C2. Also remove the rows that does not need to be updated.
Update the XML using [modify() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx)

And here is another version that does the job in the XML part of the query instead.

```
update Pages
set xmlData.modify('replace value of (/MA/A/URL/text())[1] 
                    with fn:substring((/MA/A/URL/text())[1], 1, fn:string-length((/MA/A/URL/text())[1])-1)')
where xmlData.exist('/MA/A/URL[fn:substring(text()[1], fn:string-length(text()[1]), 1) = "-"]') = 1
```

It is only possible to update one node at a time so if you have multiple URL's in in one row you have to put the code above in a loop and do the updates as long as there is something to update. You could use `@@ROWCOUNT` to check if the update did update anything and redo the update until `@@ROWCOUNT = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CHARINDEX function to check if exists a character '-' and so on you can use SUBSTIRNG function to grab only part to replace of your text.

Example:

```
declare @a varchar(100)
set @a = 'HI, TODAY IS A - BEAUTIFUL DAY'

select 
    case
        when charindex('-',@a) >= 0 then
        substring(@a, 0, charindex('-',@a)-1) + 
        substring(@a, charindex('-', @a) + 1, 100)
        else @a
    end
```

Comment: right, but I have to look into the XML code and do a find replace... so an update